# What is the best approach for giving route names in flutter and managing route?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

Thanks in advance,
As we all know that we can assign names to pages for route and use Navigator.pushNamed() with this, but what is the best approach?

What I do is to put the route name as a static string in the class itself,

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
    static const String id = "/home";
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return  widget;
    }
}
```

So now when I'm assign route in MaterialApp as

```
   routes: {
      Home.id: (context) => Home(),
    }
```

and now whenever I'm routing the page, I know which page I'm routing to

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, Home.id);
```

But I've seen people having a different file of routes as

```
class Routes {
   static const String home = "/home";
   static Map<String, Widget Function(BuildContext) routes = {
     home: (context) => Home(),
   }
}

//MaterialApp
routes: Routes.routes
```

So now can anyone tell me which is the best approach and which one should I use, which is best with performance.

And any better way to manage routing?

Comment: I believe there is no difference in performance since in the second case you just moved a map into separate class. I used to keep in in the same class, but recently I noticed that it become too bloated due to many routes, so I switched to the second variant.

Comment: I'm using the way like the second one because I don't need to import the route where I'm going to push.

Comment: If your project is large then you can use second way, otherwise used first way. Any of the two methods have not performance issue. Thank you

Comment: @obywan why does it gets bloated with only one line? I don't understand wdym.

Comment: @HassanAnsari I meant not home route, but all other routes (routes map of the Material app). If you have pretty complex application and have all that routes declared you will get pretty big map. So that's why I separated it into another file.

Comment: @obywan Oh Okay, I use separate file too, but I use onGenerateRoute instead

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use getX package which can be found at:
https://pub.dev/packages/get

This is very efficient and easy to use for routing and State Management as well.

You can import getX package and use in place of material space:

```
GetMaterialApp( // Before: MaterialApp(
  home: MyHome(),
)
```

Here Routes of Screens can be defined as:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    GetMaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/', page: () => MyHomePage()),
        GetPage(name: '/second', page: () => Second()),
        GetPage(
          name: '/third',
          page: () => Third(),
          transition: Transition.zoom  
        ),
      ],
    )
  );
}
```

Named routing can be used for this.

```
Get.toNamed("/NextScreen", arguments: 'Get is the best');
```

Routing without getting back to previous screen.

```
Get.offNamed("/NextScreen");
```